# Accordion webpart in SharePoint 2010 choppy when selected

Tags: 2010, jquery

I'm using the script (link provided) and it is working for me without having to do much. But the problem is the script is very choppy and when I select a webpart, it doesn't have the smooth effect when the accordion drops down. What is this script missing as I cannot figure it out.
[Link to site with script](http://www.markrackley.net/2013/04/29/sharepoint-2013-office-365-web-parts-in-a-jquery-ui-accordion/)

Comment: I am assuming you are using the same references: 
<!-- Reference the jQueryUI theme's stylesheet on the Google CDN. Here we're using the "Start" theme --> 
<link  type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/themes/start/jquery-ui.css" /> 
<!-- Reference jQuery on the Google CDN --> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Reference jQueryUI on the Google CDN --> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: Can you check the console tab for error (something not loading completely)

Comment: Yes I am...How would I check the console for errors?

Comment: From the Developer Tools on your browser (Hit F12). Click on the console tab and check what errors you are getting!

Comment: No error. But this warning: SEC7115: :visited and :link styles can only differ by color. Some styles were not applied to :visited.

Answer (score 1):

```
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content {
    padding: 1em 2.2em;
}
```

The issue is with this css. If you change it to px instead of em, it functions correctly.

Comment: I saw some post and tried that too.    
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content {
 padding: 1px 2.2px;
 border-top: 0;
 overflow: auto;

Comment: Change the references to get the CSS & JS from local.

Comment: I have the files ref locally too. It's still choppy.

Comment: Let me re-do this entire thing from start to finish. I'll report back once completed.

Comment: Sure ... If you need some help than please let me know

Comment: Still the same. Could it be that I'm linking the content webpart to my txt file?

Comment: Please try this if it works for you...http://sonnyeom.com/wordpress/wpaccordify-make-any-microsoft-sharepoint-web-part-zone-an-accordion/